# Uncaught Type Error When I want to delete by ID

Tags: axios, vuejs3

I'am using Vue 3.0.0 and Axios 0.21.1. I want to delete the data in the JSON file according to the id. There is no problem adding and fetching but when I want to delete it I'm getting the following error with my code.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

Here is my delete method:

```js
deleteToDo(todoList){
            axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/todoList/${todoList.id}`).then(response_delete =>{
                console.log(response_delete)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        }
```

Add method:

```js
addToDo(e){
            const sendData = {
                description : e.target.value,
                date : new Date()
            }
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/todoList', sendData).then(response_result =>{
                console.log(response_result)
            })
            
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, `todoList` you passed to the method `deleteToDo` should be undefined, you can add a console there to check if this is the cause.

And guessing you should pass todoItem rather than todoList to the method? Since you have only posted few code...